# Namespace 'NodeJS' has no exported member 'Require'

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, electron, node-modules

I'm new in Electron.. and i just following this guide:
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/integrate-angular-7-with-electronjs/?ref=rp

but, i don't know why, i can't continue the step 4, on accessing the electron, and keep popping this when doing build or even just serve.

Error: node_modules/electron/electron.d.ts:6594:21 - error TS2694: Namespace 'NodeJS' has no exported member 'Require'.

6594     require: NodeJS.Require;
~~~~~~~

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! pemberkasan@0.2.0 electron: `ng build --prod && electron .`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the pemberkasan@0.2.0 electron script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

i hope anyone here, understand with this and able to solve this. thank you! because my goal is to connect ipcMain, using ipcRenderer that i triggered on Angular Services.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I believe this problem happened because of an old version of `@types/node`, as Angular uses TypeScript as its backbone.

`npm update` itself wouldn't work if the update is a breaking change.

In order to fix this, update your `package.json` to use the latest version of `@types/node`, at this time of writing `14.14.33`. You can update it manually by editing that file.

After updating your `@types/node`, run `npm install` again, then serve it, and it should work.

If it still fails, update your Angular CLI to the latest version by using `npm uninstall -g @angular/cli`, then `npm install -g @angular/cli`. You might be using an outdated Angular CLI.

Answer (score 0):

Try these two steps:

1. Delete the node_modules folder and run

`$ npm install`

2. If this doesn't work, it might be to do with an outdated `@types/node` dependency. Try running:

`$ npm update @types/node`

Comment: tried, but not works for me.. have any other idea maybe?